# Header image not displaying at same size in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox, image-processing

I am placing live text from an exported excel document as html, into an old pdf location for seo purposes. I believe the page was originally created as a wordpress template, and is an aspx file which is annoying because it has so many stacked divs.

At first I tried to embed the html document into the pdf location as a reference file, but it was displaying horrible for responsive, so I pasted the inline table data and now it's displaying and functioning mostly properly. I lost some formatting css due to pasting it inline and most likely that is the reason.

However the issue I am having now is with the header image displaying differently in firefox and chrome.

Here is a code snippit for the image:
`<img src="/imgs/dev/LILACheader.jpg" alt=“Lilac”  class="img" style="margin-top:25px; width::100%; max-width: 100%; border: none;>`

When I use the above it renders correctly in Chrome and not Firefox, but when I add this to the inline styles:
`height:auto; and/or vertical-align:middle;`

then it's right in FF and not in Chrome.

Help! The table width is 1007px and I have made the image header 1007px as well but I cannot get it to work for both! I have a feeling it is from the extra pixels in the table border data but I can't seem to fix the issue.

Page in question: http://www.michells.com/perennials

Thanks!!

ps I have 2 screenshots I tried to attach or link but I don't think I have enough rep yet, so I can't even post hosted ones either. lol

[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS4fz.png)

Comment: Why are there two colons next to each other `width ::100%`

Comment: Make sure you end your in line styling with quotation `style=""`

Comment: I adjusted the double colon thanks!

Comment: Actually when that width 100% was validated then it spanned the whole page width, not container width which should be the same as table width.... 1007....

Comment: I just tried width: auto, and closed the inline style properly. Still wrong on firefox and right on chrome.

Comment: Do I need a reference to the height?

Comment: Set the width to match the Nav Bar.

Comment: So if your nav bar 75% do width of 75%

Comment: That won't work because then it will be 75% of page width and act responsively with the table grid.

Comment: I have the width set to 1007px so that it will display @ full size... if I put 100% it will span the entire page.

Comment: If you trying to match the table width then just do width: 1007px height:auto;

Comment: what header image are we talking about the one at top of purple flowers?

Comment: yes the purple flowers have a good width on chrome and the wrong one in FF... Is there a preset border style in FF I'm not aware of that I need to clear?

Comment: Is it in side a div/container the image?

Comment: I added height: auto... no luck

Comment: @Tarson yes, should I put it into a table cell? Or add another header row and put it in there?

Comment: Let me do some testing in 10Min and I'll give u some feedback

Comment: I just don't see why it would display wrong in FF... is that happening to you also or maybe just my browser? Safari looks good too surprisingly, ha.

Comment: thank you @Tarson!!! Huge help... the architecture of this page is crap just heads up :)

Comment: I added a screenshot above from FF so you can see the misalign.

Comment: So to be sure what you want. You want The image to be directly above the Table? You don't want the space between. Correct?

Comment: That is the other item I'm working on currently, but if you look on firefox the width will be centered but it won't match the table width. On chrome/IE/safari they widths are the same on image and table.

Comment: Do you think it has to do with vertical align or height? Or is there an innate firefox image property that adds border/margin/padding?

Comment: There is a element `<p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"></p>` That is causing the hug gap between.

Comment: That thing though with FF that I'm now seeing is really strange

Comment: I removed the spacing element and it looks much better. There is still a small disconnect I would imagine is from the border styles?

Comment: And yea the image size thing is really strange... there must be an innate FF style for img tags? or do you think it's border related to the table text?

Comment: Probably borders. Something with FF for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img tag was outside the table, but inside the container. Clearly Firefox has some innate border or margin properties to clear, so  I was able to span full width by putting the img tag INTO the table and then adding inline style properties. Once it was INSIDE the table I changed full width (1007px) to 100% and it responds appropriately now.

When the image was outside the table it was adhering to PAGE and container properties, as now it functions properly due to using the TABLE properties from being inside an actual cell.

Hopefully this can help someone else before they get stuck like me. 
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of the issue of why the `PX` were not displaying right even with `padding and margin` equaling 0. But I have got something that will resolve the issue with FF not able to process the dimensions right. 
The code below will show you how to setup:

```
<center> !--You put inside your exciting center tag-->
<div id="table-stylesheet">
!--This is where your table and Table header Image is going to be-->
</div>
</center>
```

Then in your CSS just simply add this:

```
#table-stylesheet{
width: 1007px;
}
```

After that's all completed refresh FireFox make sure the StyleSheet was updated and you should see that the Header image is now flush with the table.

Comment: So basically add the `<div id="table-stylesheet">` and the new CSS.

Comment: Thank you! It's an external stylesheet hopefully I have access to it and can apply the new division to make it work. I'll update later

Comment: What about adding a row at the top and putting the image in the new row, within the table?

Comment: @Matteb Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Not quite working on FF yet... I am trying to find out where to put the css width since it's a pretty outdated responsive architecture.

Comment: I feel like there is a FF clear I can utilize inline in this specific case I think inline is the way to go

Comment: FINALLY SUCCESS. I set the inline image width to 100% instead of 1007px and put the img into the top cell and VOILA!! 100% table width.

Comment: The image has adapted the border properties so we may or may not use them as is with a 1px border.

Comment: @Matteb forgot to tell you to set that as 100% width, sorry

Comment: I used your recommendation to make the div tag outside of the table but inside my center tags... but I'm not sure that was the fix because it was still happening in firefox coming in at a different px width. I strongly think there is a weird FF property here because once the image was inside the table then 100% span was of the table container not the page container if that make sense.

Comment: I was finding a wide array of reasons why the innate mozilla css was rendering a different width than other browsers. One was that it adds/removes borders to linked images.... even though this one wasn't a link. Another was that it adds or removes border under the :collapse command and likely this is the reason here because the table data that excel exported utilized that border-collapse:collapse which likely made the header remove one extra pixel border on each side making it about 2-4 pixels too small.

Comment: I also had some success setting a fixed width and using :auto for height because then if it's using % widths you're allowing for the height to adjust liquid according to the width. Most likely my problem was a combo of all 3 but popping header into a top cell, and changing the width from px to % easily solved my issue!